# WPF DataGrid PanningMode programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to set the panning mode of datagrid that is being programmatically generated.  In XAML I would do this:

```
ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalOnly"
```

Problem is I cannot figure out how to do this programmatically.

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: @Xaphann do `ScrollViewer.SetPanningMode(myDataGrid, PanningMode.VerticalOnly);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this programmatically you have two possibilities.

Either you set the [PanningMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your scrollviewer object directly:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
scrollViewer.PanningMode = PanningMode.VerticalOnly;
```

Or (as already pointed out in the comments) you use the [ScrollViewer.SetPanningMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.setpanningmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
ScrollViewer.SetPanningMode(scrollViewer, PanningMode.VerticalOnly);
```